# How to reset values on each page view

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a basic app in SpringMVC.  All of my controllers extend a super class shown below. 
The problem here is that the `cssFiles` and `jsFiles` are not reset every time a controller method is touched.  So I end up with `content/view.js` being loaded `x+1` times for every page view.  If I've loaded the page 3 times, it'll contain 4x `content/view.js` files.

I'm seeing these values be appended to each time the page is loaded.  Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

```
public class Controller {
    private List<String> cssFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<String> jsFiles = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Controller () {
        this.addCss("global");

        this.addJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min");
        this.includejQueryUI();
        this.addJs("global");
    }

    public ModelAndView prepareModel (ModelAndView model) {

        model.addObject("cssFiles", cssFiles);
        model.addObject("jsFiles", jsFiles);

        return model;
    }
    public ModelAndView prepareModel (ModelAndView model, String title) {
        model.addObject("title", title);

        return prepareModel(model);
    }

    /*
     * Add a css file to the page
     */
    public void addCss (String cssPath) {
        if (cssPath.indexOf("://") < 1) {
            cssPath = "/cmt/css/"+cssPath;
        }

        cssFiles.add(cssFiles.size(), cssPath);
    }

    /*
     * Add a javascript file to the page
     */
    public void addJs (String jsPath) {
        if (jsPath.indexOf("://") < 1) {
            jsPath = "/cmt/js/"+jsPath;
        }

        jsFiles.add(jsFiles.size(), jsPath);
    }

    /**
     * Add a Rich Text Editor (TinyMCE) library to the page
     */
    public void includeRichTextEditor() {
        addJs("../lib/tiny_mce-3.5b3/tiny_mce");
    }

    /**
     * Add the jQuery UI library to the page
     */
    public void includejQueryUI() {
        addCss("../lib/jquery-ui-1.8.19/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom");
        addJs("../lib/jquery-ui-1.8.19/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min");
    }
}
```

I'm still struggling to determine the cause of this issue.... any ideas?

Part of web.xml

```
<!-- Standard spring configuration -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Web MVC dispatcher servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: aside from your question have you looked at sitemesh to do page decoration? I've never seen css/js files served out like this, usually there's a main jspx that decorates every page and it contains all the css and js inclusions using standard html...

Comment: How is the controller defined in the spring configuration? If you do not reset the lits manually before each request, the controller should be defined to be request-scoped

Comment: I've updated this post with my configuration.  Is this what you were talking about?  I'm not sure what I should be adjusting here.

Comment: @Dominik - I forgot to include your name so you'd get an update when I provided my configuration

Comment: The default in spring is, that all beans are instatiated in singleton scope, i.e reused between requests. If you want a different behavior (e.g. a new instance for every request) you would have to configure this in your spring configuration files (seems you use xml configuration files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't test this code, the obvious thing what I'd try is :

```
public class Controller {
    private List<String> cssFiles;
    private List<String> jsFiles;
.......
 public Controller () {
        cssFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        jsFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.addCss("global");
        this.addJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min");
        this.includejQueryUI();
        this.addJs("global");
    }
```

Can you ellaborate what you mean by reset in `are not reset every time a controller method is touched`

**I've misunderstood your question at first here is revised version :**

```
<html>
<head>
<!--Above content is header-->
<!--Specific CSS for edit.jsp here-->
<!--Or if you want to override css classes inside <style></style>-->
</head>
<body>
<!--Load specific edit.jsp javascript at the end of the body tag-->
<!--Below content is footer-->
</body>
</html>
```

If you need to override some javascript then put the edit.jsp specific js after the `html` tag. So your edit file would look like this :

```
<%@include file="header.jsp" %>
</head>
<body>
<!--some edit.jsp content -->
<%@include file="footer.jsp" %>
```

Comment: That doesn't work, I've tried it.  if I do `this.addCss('content/edit');`, all java pages served to that user's session will always have that css file loaded.  What I need is for only the specific page to have it

Comment: @Webnet hmm interesting why don't you add those css styles in your jsp files? Why reason would you do this from controller?

Comment: I need to control the order in which the JS/CSS files are loaded but also ensure that css files are loaded within the `<head>` tag and js files are loaded just before the `</body>` tag.  It's 5x easier to do that within a controller than JSP views.  Unless I could have a css hashmap or something I can append to within my views...

Comment: There's also a great benefit to being able to use something like `this.includejQueryUI()` and have it include  the js file (loaded in the footer) and css file (loaded in the header).

Comment: @Webnet I understand but I have solved that issue with header/footer templates. Header containing all until `body` tag and footer containing `/body` and after including javascript and it works fine for me. I still think there is no need to do this(what you're trying to do that is).

Comment: - Your name is too short for the autocomplete to pick it up - Secondly, if my content/edit.jsp includes both header and footer, how should edit.jsp tell footer to load a specific js file?  Or how should it tell header.jsp to load a specific css file?

Comment: @Webnet Here take a look at my updated answer, I hope that clarifies it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do

```
cssFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
jsFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
```

in the constructor if the parent controller is always alive?

How are you invoking the parent constructor's methods?

Comment: Unfortunately that does not resolve the issue, once I've added a CSS or JS file it stays included on all the pages I access throughout the site until I kill my session.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are adding the js and css files to your views are wrong.

You should add the resource handlers for the css and js files in the the servlet xml configuration file. I use the following code for the same.

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

This will skip the Spring's Dispathcer Servlet for the all the resources in the **resources** folder of your web application root.

After doing this you just needs to include them in your jsp files wherever you need them.

Cheeers...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of `ArrayList`.

```
private Set<String> cssFiles = new HashSet<String>();
private Set<String> jsFiles = new HashSet<String>();
```

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets
>   contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at
>   most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models
>   the mathematical set abstraction.

Answer (score -1):

try to use `Set` instead of `ArrayList`.