# How to syntactically improve include statements

Tags: java, jsp

With the below code I need to maintain the inclusion load order but I'm wondering if there's a better way to accomplish this syntactically without using so many `<%` `%>`

**base.jsp**

```
<%

List<String> cssFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> jsFiles = new ArrayList<String>();

/*
 * Load all CSS/JS files we want on every page
 */

%>
<%@ include file="includes/jquery.jsp" %>
<%

cssFiles.add("/css/global");
jsFiles.add("/js/global");

%>
<%@ include file="includes/jquery_ui.jsp" %>
```

**view.jsp**

```
<%@ include file="../base.jsp" %>
<% cssFiles.add("/css/content/view"); %>
<%@ include file="../header.jsp" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A significantly better way would be to use Model-View-Controller pattern and move all code into Controller, so your JSPs won't have that many `<% %>` in a first place.

Comment: This is how I originally had everything setup... but I ran into issues with it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352472/how-to-reset-values-on-each-page-view/10484709

Comment: That issue is easily fixed by using a Set instead of List, so all elements in collection are unique.

Comment: No, the other problem wasn't just that items were unique, it was that on Page A I wanted to have 2 css files, on Page B I wanted only 1 css file, then page 5 I wanted 5 CSS files.  That method didn't erase data from the cssFiles array when the page changed, it only added to it.

Comment: But of course. In your Controller class you had those collections defined as controller class members, yet Controller instance is the same between http requests, so you need to create those collections for each request.

Comment: And that is why it is a bad idea. Anyways, not going to argue with you. I believe your question had been answered already.

Comment: I would prefer to load CSS/JS files via the controller, I just haven't found a method that allows me to control these effectively.  If you have one, I'd love to hear more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Scriptlet code snippets of the form `<% /*foo*/ %>` should not be required at all in a modern JSP application. Inject data into the view using the Expression Language and leverage tag libraries for display logic.

Use a MVC approach to development. Developers generally leverage a framework (of which there are many.)

At the very least, use a [servlet as a controller and just utilize the JSP as the view](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/jsp/jsp_scriptless_jsp.htm).

Comment: I haven't yet found a good method of including CSS/JS files in my application.  Doing this within JSPs is the only way I have found to maintain control over the loading order, and be sure that only the specific css/js files get loaded on pages where they're needed.